# How does the loopback interface work

Tags: linux, network-interface

there are strange things:

on my virtualbox：
centos7

Interfaces：

```
enp0s3: 192.168.10.110/24
lo:0 10.0.3.110/24 (ip alias)
```

route：

```
default via 10.0.3.2 dev lo
192.168.10.0/24 dev enp0s3

enp0s3 is plugged in 10.0.3.0/24
```

I have enabled the ip_forward (net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1)

---

My Question：

`ping 10.0.3.2` works，but why?

`tcpdump` can't get packets on `enp0s3`，but does get packets on `lo`.

The default route is `lo`; why does `ping 10.0.3.2` work? Why can't I get packets on `enp0s3`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The loopback interface is a virtual interface. The only purpose of the loopback interface is to return the packets sent to it, i.e. whatever you send to it is received on the interface. It makes little sense to put a default route on the loopback interface, because the only place it can send packets to is the imaginary piece of wire that is looped from the output of the interface to the input. There is nothing that can change this behaviour of the loopback interface, that's what it is coded to do.

When you ping 10.0.3.2, the reply does not come from some external device, but from the loopback interface itself. When you add an address on the loopback interface with e.g.

```
sudo ip addr add 10.0.3.1/24 dev lo
```

a route to `10.0.3.0/24` is added. You can see this with

```
ip route show table local
```

Something like

```
local 10.0.3.0/24 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 10.0.3.1
```

should show up. This routing table entry tells that a packet sent to any address between `10.0.3.1` and `10.0.3.254` is sent via the `lo` interface, from which it is immediately returned.

EDIT: clarification as a response to the comment below.

Here is what happens when you ping 10.0.3.2: the kernel gets an IP packet for delivery with a destination address 10.0.3.2. Just like with any packet to be delivered, the kernel consults the routing table. In this case the matching entry is this: `local 10.0.3.0/24 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 10.0.3.1`, which says the packet should be delivered via the `lo` interface with the source address 10.0.3.1.

Now, because the packet was given to the `lo` interface, the loopback interface does what it normally does: it takes the packet off the send queue and puts it on the receive queue. From the kernel's point of view, we have now received an incoming packet ready for consumption by a server process listening on a socket. (In the case of ping, the kernel processes it internally.) We have now received a "remote" ICMP packet with a destination address of 10.0.3.2, which is arguably not one of our local addresses, but it was delivered to the loopback interface nonetheless.

Next, the kernel sends a response to the ping: an ICMP response packet with the addresses reversed: 10.0.3.2 as source address and 10.0.3.1 as destination. This is delivered via the loopback interface back to the ping program, which shows that we got a reply from 10.0.3.2.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I still don't know why can I recieve the icmp response from 10.0.3.2. Is the icmp response from my centos7?This IP is not mine.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your other question, "Why can't I get packets on enp0s3?"

It's pointed to the LAN at 192.168.10.0/24

Therefore, unless you have a server on the LAN that responds to package delivery requests, you get nada via that route.